# How can I prevent additional navigation bar on top of MasterDetailPage (Xamarin on Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating an application in Xamarin Forms (4.0) for Android (Android 8.1).
My main page is a MasterDetailPage where I set the detail page to:

```
this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new SomePage());
```

When I want to navigate the detail to another page (so that the 'back' button works correctly) I just do:

```
this.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new SomeOtherPage());
```

This all works fine but I am left with an additionl navigation bar with the back button:

[image]

If I do `NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);` the back button goes away but the navigation bar is left so I have a big blue rectangle on top of my page. If I do `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` then both the navigation bar **and** the titlebar (with hamburger menu) dissappear! Is there a way to just hide the navigation bar with the back button but leave the master/detail title bar (with hamburger menu)?

Comment: What is hamburger menu is no longer visible. Only the title is left? Can you add more code or a screenshot? One instance of NavigationPage is enough for you as Jason said.

Comment: Did you tested it on real device?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment. No I have not tested it on a real device. Copy/pasted from my other comment: 'You can see the effect if you create a new Cross-Platform Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) in VS2017/2019. The generated application has a master/detail page with a list of items. If you tap on an item your proceed to the item details form. When this happens you loose the master/detail hamburger menu. You can avoid this by wrapping the detail page in NavigationPage, however this shows an extra back button bar (as visible in my original screenshot)'.

Comment: The effect I want to achieve is to have the Master/detail menu available all the time, even if the Detail page navigates somewhere else. This actually works quite nicely if I wrap the detail page into NavigationPage ... but I get two titlebars.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the way I've tried to make it work is not really supported by Xamarin Forms. If you navigate the Detail away to another page you effectively loose access to the Master part of the MasterDetailPage (at least on some devices). My attempt to avoid this by wrapping the target Detail page into another NavigationPage works in the Emulator but that is simply by accident.

Answer (score 0):

you only need one instance of `NavigationPage`

```
this.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new SomeOtherPage());
```

Comment: If I do that then the hamburger menu is no longer visible. Only the title is left.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the new `MasterDetailPage` to the root and then handle back pressed. As this isn't suppose to work you must hack a bit.

Comment: > "As this isn't suppose to work you must hack a bit".  
Why do you say that this isn't supposed to work? The documentation clearly states that the MasterDetailPage Detail should not be set to a regular content page but rather wrapped in NavigationPage. As the main purpose of the NavigationPage is to provide navigation it would be odd to not work. 
Anyway everythin works as it should (the navigation works perfectly), I just want to remove the navigation bar without removing the MasterDetailPage menu button.

Comment: But just to note that everyone already said you shouldn't push the new page wrapped in the NavigationController. It is like that you are asking for a truck to take your load and then also ask to create a new truck inside that truck for your load. And if you look at the screenshot it looks exactly as I described in this example, you have a truck inside a truck and they behave unexpectedly because it is not something one is expected to do at all.

Comment: Please see my answer to Jason. If I do not wrap the page in NavigationPage (in other words if I do this.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new SomeOtherPage())) then the hamburger menu dissapears. Only the title is left. I can no longer access the master page.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am talking about. That isn’t allowed. And even in the native app you won’t have the hamburger if you navigate. That’s not how the navigation works on Android. If you wish some custom solution you can use some hack or build it from the scratch. If you want to ignore than official Microsoft employee and several users with quite a lot of points that all give exact the same advice.... please don’t reply.

Comment: I am asking a simple question - can I hide the additional bar. If you would have answered 'that is not possible due to X/Y' I would have accepted your answer. As for 'pretend to be smarter' sentence I really do not understand what is your problem. If this question 'offends' you in some way then just move on and ignore it.

Comment: I gave you the solution for that. As it seems that you don’t like it, it is impossible to answer your question - it is hard to say what someone might like.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `MainPage` is set only to `MasterDetailPage`.
Once, I had a case that somebody did something like this:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailPage());
```

Of course, it should be defined like:

```
MainPage = new MasterDetailPage();
```

Then, your `DetailPage` should be defined only once as it follows:

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
```

Comment: > MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailPage());    
The MasterDetailPage is the main page of the application, it is not wrapped in navigation page. 

>MainPage = new MasterDetailPage();    
This is what I do.

> DetailPage = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());    
You mean Detail = = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
This is also what I do. The problem is when I navigate to a different detail page (see original question).

Comment: Can you provide more details about this navigation stuff you're doing? How exactly do you navigate? Are you using anything like Prism or just default Navigation service?

Comment: You can see the effect if you create a new Cross-Platform Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) in VS2017/2019. The generated application has a master/detail page with a list of items. If you tap on an item your proceed to the item details form. When this happens you loose the master/detail hamburger menu. You can avoid this by wrapping the detail page in NavigationPage, however this shows an extra back button bar (as visible in my original screenshot).

Comment: Ok, just as somebody wrote, that is not expected behaviour on all platforms.
The reason is that if you would do any navigation from your root page, you would not have a way to go back (only by using back button).
Default behavior is that your root detail page has hamburger menu, as soon as you navigate somewhere, instead of hamburger menu icon, it will display back button.
Still, you can swipe from left to pull out menu.
Of course, there is a way to hack this, but you would have to write custom renderers for each platform.
I know how to do it for Android, not really sure about iOS.